# Can't seem to get a non-zero IntPtr from a byte[] instance variable

Tags: c#, pointers, pinvoke

I've found *many* ways of getting an `IntPtr` from a `byte[]`, all of which I could successfully pass into external unmanaged code, but *only* if I allocate the `byte[]` on the stack. Attempting to do the same on a `byte[]` instance variable, I get a `null` (`IntPtr.Zero`) result, no matter which method of getting an `IntPtr` I choose. I haven't found any information on whether or not instance variables are treated differently than those allocated on the stack, in this case.

Here is what I would like to use to acquire a valid `IntPtr` to a `byte[]` instance variable:

```
GCHandle pinned = GCHandle.Alloc(outBytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ptr = pinned.AddrOfPinnedObject();

// Always true, for reasons I'm unaware.
if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero) {}

pinned.Free();
```

Thanks!

Comment: By 'on the stack' do you mean with `stackalloc`?

Comment: I mean just declaring a byte[] on the local scope, like so: `byte[] outBytes = new byte[GetNumBytes()]`. My terminology may be incorrect, considering I'm using `new`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code where this doesn't work? Is it a global array? A member of an object? A reference passed into a function?

Comment: The `IntPtr ptr` is zero if `outBytes` is a member of an object (instance variable). I'll flesh out the code in my question, a little bit.

Comment: Unrelated, but consider using a try-finally clause to ensure that `pinned.Free()` always runs even if your marshaling code throws an exception. Otherwise you risk leaking memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time that `GCHandle.Alloc( thing, GCHandleType.Pinned )` results in a handle to `IntPtr.Zero` is when `thing` is null.

Your byte array reference is null when you provide it to `GCHandle.Alloc()`.

Here's where it returns zero:

```
public class ZeroTest
{
    private byte[] someArray;

    public Test()
    {
        this.someArray = null;
    }

    public void DoMarshal()
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc( this.someArray, GCHandleType.Pinned );

        try
        {
            // Prints '0'.
            Console.Out.WriteLine( handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToString() );
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's where it returns non-zero:

```
public class Test
{
    private byte[] someArray;

    public Test()
    {
        this.someArray = new byte[1];
    }

    public void DoMarshal()
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc( this.someArray, GCHandleType.Pinned );

        try
        {
            // Prints a non-zero address, like '650180924952'.
            Console.Out.WriteLine( handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToString() );
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Going through my code again to flesh out my code above did reveal to me, my mistake. Where I was looking to initialize the member variable, I was instead declaring a local variable, so my member variable was indeed `null`. I think I should eat something... Thanks for the help!